# How can I show that a curve $\gamma(t) = t+it \sin(1/t)$ is continous but not rectifiable

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have this problem:

> Show that the curve defined by setting $\gamma(t)=t+it\sin(1/t)$  for $0 < t \leq 1$ and $\gamma(0)=0$ is continuous but not rectifiable.
>
> (**Hint:**
> it is not necessary to compute the arc-length precisely; a lower bound that goes to infinity will suffice.  Graph the curve to discover some convenient partitions with which to generate such lower bounds. Alternatively, one can apply the arc-length formula to some sub-curves of \gamma)

My strategy was to graph the curve. The curve $t\sin(1/t)$ looks like the following:

[image: page1]

I want to conjoin the point at the trough of one curve to the peak of the next. I will get a line. Similarly, that can be done for the whole graph. If I can show that these lines end up like a sequence that goes to infinity, then I am done. How do I begin to approximate the length of these lines?

Answer (score 1):

On each interval $I_k:=\left(\frac{1}{2\pi(k+1)},\frac{1}{2\pi k}\right];\ k\ge 1,\ \sin(1/t)$ executes a cycle and so $L_{\gamma|_{I_k}}>2\left(\frac{1}{2\pi(k+1)}\right)$ and since the $(I_k)$ are disjoint, it follows that $L_{\gamma}>\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{k+1}, $ which diverges.

Comment: how is K > 6? and how is $L_\gamma > 2$? $\gamma$ is a curve given by the equation as in the title @Matematleta

Comment: OK, then I will modify my answer. Please edit your question.

Comment: Sorry it is edited now @Matamatleta.

Comment: Could you please give the rationale for how the first expression for $L_{\gamma I_k}$ and $L_\gamma$? Why they are what they have been stated to be.

Comment: I also would like some explanation on how you chose the interval to be $(\frac{1}{2 \pi (k+1)} , \frac{1}{2 \pi k})$

Comment: on each $I_k$ the vertical extent of $\gamma$ at least $\frac{1}{2\pi(k+1)}$ times the max - min of the sine which is $2$. Now sum up all the lengths.

Comment: I chose the intervals that way because it is over these intervals that the sine of $1/t$ executes exactly one cycle.

Comment: Thanks @Matematleta.

Comment: Glad to help....